# How can this inline onClick code can replaced with addEventListner?

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

The code given utilizes old methods and ES5. But, I am unable to convert it in ES6 by using addEventListner.

I am facing problem regarding parameters such as different city names used in onClick() function.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but this might work:

```
 tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
 for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].removeAttribute('onclick');
    tablinks[i].addEventListener('click', function() { 
       openCity(evt, evt.currentTarget.innerHTML());
    }, false);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to get rid of openCity event and solve it withour using onClick anwhere

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing wrong with your comment, but rather that there literally is no element on the page with the id "defaultOpen", so this is where the error comes from.

Answer (score 1):

For the JavaScript part:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tablinks');
for(var i = 0;i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var target = elements[i].getAttribute('data-target');
        openCity(evt, document.querySelector(target));
    }, false);
}
```

Edit your HTML to look like this:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#London">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Paris">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Tokyo">Tokyo</button>
</div>
```

Why are we using `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`? So that we can use any CSS selector to target our tabs. E.g. `#tabs .pages`.

Why are we using `data-target`? So that we can type anything we want into the element body.